# Use data entry form and auto populate certain fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, let's call them `employees` and `customers`.

`employees` is pretty basic:

```
ID | title | emp_name | building | email | phone
```

`customers` is not much different:

```
ID | cust_name | address | phone | emp_title | emp_name
```

I have a form that is used for data entry into `customers`. Two of the fields are `employee_title` and `employee_name`.

`employee_name` is a combo box with the Control Source as `employee_name` and the Row Source is `SELECT [employees].emp_name FROM employees;`. There is also an After Update event that requerys `employee_title`.

For `employee_title` the Control Source is `=DLookUp("title","employees","emp_name = '" & [employee_name] & "'")`.

This works fine for the form itself. After selecting the employee's name from the dropdown, it displays the employee's title correctly. However, the employee's title is not inserted into the `customers` table (everything else is inserted correctly). I am not completely familiar with MS Access, but I'm 99% sure this is because the Control Source is a DLookUp and not a reference to the table.

So, how do I get the employee's title to show up on the form AND insert into the customer's table?

Comment: You shouldn't really be saving the employee name and title in the customers record, simply the ID of the employee. You then link the Employees table to your customers table to bring that data in when you need it. If an employee changes name (get married) for instance the displayed record would be automatically updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a little VBA to handle this properly.

First, set the control source of `employee_title` to `emp_title` (or `title`, or `employee_title`, your question is a bit vague about the name of this column).

Then, add the following code to the `employee_name` combo box.

```
Private Sub employee_name_AfterUpdate()
    employee_title = DLookUp("title","employees","emp_name = '" & employee_name & "'")
End Sub
```

Comment: This works but only after the entry is made to the table. In other words, the title does not show up until you enter the form then go back and look at the form.

Comment: You could move it to the OnChange event to make it show earlier, but then you might run into trouble with it already trying to show when the name is not yet fully typed.

Comment: That didn't work either, but no big deal. The main thing was to get it into the table.

Comment: Note that if your old solution did work, you could just use both. You could hide the field my code is using, and only show yours.